# generar nro de copias controlado por usuario de una tablix ReportViewer en Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, reportviewer

Proyecto en Winforms c#.

Estoy queriendo generar copias de un reporte a traves de un boton y un numericUpDown en un Form.
En el reporte tengo una tabla, que recupera los datos de precio, cod.barras, descripción artículo, y me genera tal como deseo pero 1 sola vez porque solo tengo una tabla. Lo que deseo y que no encuentro como escribir el código es para que el usuario coloque cuantas veces quiere generar la copia de esa tabla, uno debajo del otro. Así es como lo tengo, en este ejemplo quiero 4 copias pero me sale 1 porque me falta una parte del codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es que si el usuario coloca 4 etiquetas entonces aparezca así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito la ayuda es esta parte del código que hace el botón para tener en cuenta el valor del NumericUpDown y replicar lo que ya me genera de forma que aparezca uno abajo del otro. La idea es que se pueda enviar la impresion de eso a una etiquetadora por lo que requiero que la distancia entre uno y el siguiente poder controlarlo para ajustar en funcion del tamano de la etiqueta:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
String BARRAS = textBox3.Text;
                Int32 CODIGO = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                this.sp_code128TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSetCode128.sp_code128, CODIGO, BARRAS);
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
                {
                    //aqui iria el codigo que necesito                }
}
```